# How can I get DEX trade details from transaction from Uniswap Router

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I'm trying to understand Uniswap trade decoding. I'm looking at Swap events, and for figuring out Swap events emitted by a Uniswap token pair contract this is straightforward. However I have a Swap event which is emitted by the ERC20 token contract itself and I can't quite make sense of what's happening so I wonder if someone could explain? Thanks!

This is the transaction: `0xae3888aed74cfd92efa884d10c05b1325e9721b2b2de7e676b3c5e76ccc5a2ca`
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xae3888aed74cfd92efa884d10c05b1325e9721b2b2de7e676b3c5e76ccc5a2ca

It comes from `0x564b4B1e0671E239f04E97f03e21DaF2c5D91B80`, which looks like a regular EOA.

Sent to `0xD1A15671c772032123719a1C9bCC2182E5cb1D08`, which is a smart contract for an ERC20 token, Kermit.

It calls a function on this contract called execute that looks like this:

```
function execute(address [] calldata _addresses_, uint256 _in, uint256 _out) external {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _addresses_.length; i++) {
            emit Swap(_universal, _in, 0, 0, _out, _addresses_[i]);
            emit Transfer(_pair, _addresses_[i], _out);
        }
    }
```

with these params:

```
0       _addresses_     address[]       0x4c27BA1c4f44a487031c83818d8d1de62B8088d2
1       _in     uint256 1000000000000000000
2       _out    uint256 2296103435739971388790164659
```

This emits a Swap event,

```
0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822
1 0x3fC91A3afd70395Cd496C647d5a6CC9D4B2b7FAD (The Uniswap router)
2 0x4c27BA1c4f44a487031c83818d8d1de62B8088d2 (The address which gets the tokens)
```

Then a Transfer event:

```
0 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
1 0xb253DdD5C64A1C521D87a637C8D4bC1eCdc05411 (The token contract owner)
2 0x4c27BA1c4f44a487031c83818d8d1de62B8088d2 (The address which gets the tokens)
```

Which transfers the Kermit tokens from `0xb253DdD5C64A1C521D87a637C8D4bC1eCdc05411` to `0x4c27BA1c4f44a487031c83818d8d1de62B8088d2`

I don't understand how or where the pair contract is involved in this. The pair contract is `0xcc89ef16e9921d71a12dfbcec94e429cb58c5537`

I noticed in the erc20 contract it has this function called setup with onlyOwner perms to set a variable called _pair to something.

```
    function setup(address _pair_) external onlyOwner {
        _pair = _pair_;
    }
```

I don't know how I can see or inspect this. I'm also not sure of the indirection here. I thought instigating trades from a smart contract was something MEV bots did to enabled their transactions to either all go through or all fail, but this is the token contract firing it.

Any ideas in how I can understand this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the contract looks quite **suspicious**. The functions implemented in this ERC20 should be implemented on the router instead and called through the router.

Secondly, executing the function execute() as is, **doesn't transfer anything**. It only emits events, which Etherscan understands as a transfer and displays it as such. It seems like the developer wanted users to think their tokens were transferred.

Concerning the *pair* variable, it doesn't really play any role in this function call. If the contract was implemented correctly, then the router would be handling transactions and the pair would be accessible through router.

Comment: Thanks! I did wonder if it may be just something suspect. Cheers.